# CSplitterWnd with two panes : left pane is CTreeView, Right is CFrameWnd : Not able to set different views in Right pane

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, multiple-views, csplitterwnd

I am trying to implement a classic Windows Explorer kind of Application, 
CpliterWnd has two panes : Left pane is CLeftTreeView : public CTreeView
Right pane is CRightPaneFrame: public CFrameWnd , CRightPaneFrame has a member variable m_pCustomView.

CustomView is a class i added to a dialog resource ( edited using Resource editor and Add class wizard)

```
class CustomView : public CFormView
{

DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CustomView)

public:  // Changed to public so that i can instantiate this view on heap
CustomView();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
virtual ~CustomView();
BOOL Create(LPCTSTR A, LPCTSTR B, DWORD C,
    const RECT& D, CWnd* E, UINT F, CCreateContext* G); // To override the protected specifier of CFormView::Create()
```

MainFrame.cpp has the following entry

```
if (!m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CLeftTreeView), CSize(125, 100),   pContext) ||  !m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CRightPaneFrame), CSize(100, 100), pContext))    
{
     m_SplitterWnd.DestroyWindow();
     return FALSE;
}
```

And later on in CRightPaneFrame

```
BOOL CRightPaneFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs, CCreateContext* pContext) 
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    m_pCustomView = new CustomView;
    m_pCustomView->Create(NULL,NULL,0L,CFrameWnd::rectDefault,this,VIEW_CUSTOM, pContext);
    SetActiveView(m_pCustomView);
    m_pCustomView->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
    RecalcLayout();
    return true;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but the CustomView is not getting loaded in the right pane.

Any suggestions on changing the approach or What is wrong with the current approach ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the custom view directly into the splitter windows right side, and not inside a CFrameWnd.

```
if (!m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CLeftTreeView), CSize(125, 100), pContext) 
|| !m_SplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CCustomView), CSize(100, 100), pContext))

{
    m_SplitterWnd.DestroyWindow();
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dwo, Sorry for the delayed response.